# System.LimitException: DML currently not allowed Class.Calloutcontroller.getperformcallout: line 49, column 1

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex, dml

```
public class Calloutcontroller {
    List<Tutor__c> TutorList ;

    // public Calloutcontroller() {
    //  }
    //  public Calloutcontroller(Tutor controller) {
    //  }
    //public Calloutcontroller(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    public List<consolewrap> ConsoleWrapperList{get;set;}
    public List<consolewrap> getperformcallout(){
        TutorList = new List<Tutor__c>();
        ConsoleWrapperList = new List<consolewrap>();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        Http http = new Http();
        req.setEndpoint('http://www.itutorindia.com/angularjs/api/smallWidget/tutorHourSalesForce');
        //req.setEndpoint('http://52.24.111.14/angularjs/api/smallWidget/tutorHourSalesForce');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setHeader('Accept','application/json');
        res = http.send(req);
        if(res.getstatusCode() == 200 && res.getbody() != null){
            system.debug('Response body result is+++: ' + res.getBody());
            ConsoleWrapperList=(List<consolewrap>)json.deserialize(res.getbody(),List<consolewrap>.class);

            /* To save Aoi data in custom object tutor*/

            Tutor__c tutorObj;
            system.debug('test1++++++++');
            for (integer i = 0; i<ConsoleWrapperList.size(); i++)
            {
                system.debug('test2++++++++');
                tutorObj = new Tutor__c();
                tutorObj.Class_ID__c = Integer.valueOf(ConsoleWrapperList[i].class_id);
                tutorObj.Tutor_ID__c = Integer.valueOf(ConsoleWrapperList[i].tutor_id);
                tutorObj.Class_Time__c =date.ValueOf(ConsoleWrapperList[i].class_time);
                //system.debug('time is++++ '+tutorObj.Class_Time__c);
                //system.debug('Time values entered');
                tutorObj.Name = ConsoleWrapperList[i].tutor_name;
                tutorObj.E_Mail__c = ConsoleWrapperList[i].tutor_email;
                tutorObj.Tutor_Phone__c = ConsoleWrapperList[i].tutor_phone;
                TutorList.add(tutorObj);
               // system.debug('test3++++++++');
            }
            //system.debug('TutorList++++++++'+TutorList);
        }
        //system.debug('Time values entered222');
        upsert TutorList;
        system.debug('Time values entered+++++++');
        return ConsoleWrapperList;
    }
}

Wrapper class

    public class consolewrap {

    public String class_id{get;set;}

    public String class_time{get;set;}

    public String tutor_id{get;set;}

    public String tutor_name{get;set;}

    public String tutor_email{get;set;} 

    public String tutor_phone{get;set;}
}
```

VF PAGE

```
<apex:form >

<apex:pageBlock >

<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!performcallout}" var="wrap">

<apex:column headerValue="Class Id" value="{!wrap.class_id}"/>

<apex:column headerValue="Class Time" value="{!wrap.class_time}"/>

<apex:column headerValue="Tutor Id" value="{!wrap.tutor_id}"/>

<apex:column headerValue="Tutor Name" value="{!wrap.tutor_name}"/>

<apex:column headerValue="Tutor Email" value="{!wrap.tutor_email}"/>

<apex:column headerValue="Tutor Phone" value="{!wrap.tutor_phone}"/>

</apex:pageBlockTable>

</apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Your code above says your form is inside a Page. Are you simplifying what you pasted there and not including a Component? I've only ever seen that error when trying to submit from a Component. If that is the case, you need to set the attribute `allowDML="true"` on the Component.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000952VIAQ

per this link it could also be related to you not invoking the DML from an action method. you could try calling it from an action function on the page itself